# Change inline css of an element without an id or class

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

It's pretty simple to change the style of an element when it has a class. I thought it would be simple to change the style of an element that has no class or id too, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

The html page looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>ExamplePage</title>    
      </head>
      <body>
            <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
            <p style="display: none">The style shouldn't change</p>
            <section class="container_class">
                    <p style="display: none">The display part of the inline css should be deleted or modified to inline</p>
                    <p style="display: none">The display part of the inline css should be deleted or modified to inline</p>
                    <p style="display: none">The display part of the inline css should be deleted or modified to inline</p>
            </section>
            <p style="display: none">The style shouldn't change</p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Since I'm trying to build a google chrome extension I've been using contentscripts.
I haven't figured out how to select the specific element although I have seen something similar to this idea.
I've searched the internet on how to select a specific element based on the inline css. I couldn't find anything helpful.

This is my content.js:

```
var ps = document.querySelectorAll("section.container_class > p");

var i;
for (i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) { 
  ps.style.display = "inline";
}
```

I'm new to coding in javascript, so the code might not make sense at all. It's just an idea on how to change the inline css. I'm trying to learn by doing a mini-project like this.

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there.

The bug is in the `for` loop. It should be:

```js
var ps = document.querySelectorAll("section.container_class > p");

var i;
for (i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) { 
  ps[i].style.display = "inline";
}
```

Note the square bracket array access notation on the `ps` variable.

ie. for every iteration of the loop, access the `i`th index of the array `ps`.

Answer (score 1):

var ps is defined to array as it selected for querySelectorAll. Seems there is no number for ps array in for loop.

```
var ps = document.querySelectorAll("section.container_class > p");

var i;
for (i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) { 

//Here should be array num.

  ps[i].style.display = "inline";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"document.querySelectorAll" returns an Array containing all the elements that you have specified (in this case: "section.container_class > p"). So when you want to iterate through the entire Array you will have to use an index.
Basically all you forgot was to add [i] in your block of code.

```
var ps = document.querySelectorAll("section.container_class > p");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
ps[i].style.display = "inline";
}
```

However you should try to use the let and const keywords instead of var.
Also i is defined as a global variable and you don't want that because it might interfer with locally defined variables. So instead you should declare it in the for-loop "head".

A newer version might look something like this:

```
const PS = document.querySelectorAll("section.container_class > p");
for (let i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) ps[i].style.display = "inline";
```